# OS Error While Converting String To Raw String And Creating File

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, file, python-3.9

Im a Python Beginner. I want to make a log file for each time the program is used, here's the code;

```
import time

date1 = time.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
path = "C:\\Users\\Devisha\\Documents\\Coding\\Python\\DeviOS\\Log"
name1 = '\\Log-'
date = date1
last = '.txt'
filelog = path + name1 + date + last
b = r"{}".format(filelog)
a = open(b, 'x')
```

And when i run it, it returns this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:\Users\Devisha\Documents\Coding\Python\test.py", line 10, in 
> a = open(b, 'x')
> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\Users\Devisha\Documents\Coding\Python\DeviOS\Log\Log-14-02-2021 23:42:33.txt'

So what i want it to do is, get the date, fuse it with the beginning path (path), the file_name start (name1) and the filetype (last) and convert it into a string and then make a file.

Im using VS Code and Python 3.9.1 64-Bit

Comment: There's no need for `format`. `filelog` is already a string.

Comment: What do you mean by "convert to a raw string"? Raw only applies to string literals, not the contents of a string.

Comment: What is `x` mode supposed to be?

Comment: Have you tried to escape the space here "Log-14-02-2021 23:42:33.txt"?

Comment: @Barmar I tried adding it as the path directly without the `format` and it returned this.                                  
  File "c:\Users\Devisha\Documents\Coding\Python\test.py", line 10, in <module>
    a = open(filelog, 'x')
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\Devisha\\Documents\\Coding\\Python\\DeviOS\\Log\\Log-15-02-2021 08:22:11.txt'

Comment: @Barmar x mode is create file. and I want to convert it to a raw string so the open() command can read the path.

Comment: @Mihai I added an underscore instead of a space and it gives this error (OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\Devisha\\Documents\\Coding\\Python\\DeviOS\\Log\\Log-15-02-2021_08:28:12.txt')

Comment: You don't "convert" something to a raw string. Raw strings only exist in source code, not data. It's just a different way of writing a string literal, e.g. `"foo\\bar"` versus `r"foo\bar"`

Comment: Maybe exclusive mode doesn't work on Windows. What happens if you change to `w` mode.

Comment: @Barmar Oh, Thanks for your answers. when you change to 'w' mode, it either overwrites or if it doesn't exist, creates a file. And do you know why it gives me the error even when i put it to 'w' mode?

 [        a = open(filelog, 'w')
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\Devisha\\Documents\\Coding\\Python\\DeviOS\\Log\\Log-15-02-2021_08:48:18.txt'   ]

Comment: You're saying it creates or overwrites the file, but also gives the error? I don't know why. It's something Windows-specific, and I mostly know Unix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend the python [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html)  library for
you to use the if you want to log the code.

Comment: Thanks For The Suggestion, Its A Cool Library, easy to use and simple but it still doesn't solve the problem of the filename as a string ---------> [OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\Devisha\\Documents\\Coding\\Python\\DeviOS\\Log\\Log-15-02-2021_09:26:54.txt']

Comment: It could be the string formatting, I would really recommend using [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) to create the file path. One possible problem could be the way you define the windows path.